# Intersect two arrays in VBA (no excel)

Tags: arrays, vba

I have two string arrays with quite a few items. The items are unique in each array: I sort the array alphabetically and remove duplicates as I do so.

I want to know how many of the items in array a are also present in array b. As soon as there is even one of such items that occurs in both arrays, I "know enough".

And even though both arrays are sorted alphabetically first, doing a double loop as below is very heavy on the processor and terribly slow.

So I'm looking for an alternative, or even an other approach from the start...

````
Dim aryA(1 To 10000) As String
Dim aryB(1 To 10000) As String
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim Counter as long 

Counter = 0

'fill arrays with many values

For x = 1 to 10000
    For y = 1 to 10000
        If aryA(x) = aryB(y) Then
            counter = counter + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
Next x

If Flag = True Then
    'run amazing code here
End If
    
End Sub```


Thanks!
````

Comment: What is "terribly slow" in time? And what size Arrays (original, not from this code)?

Comment: Thanks for the Filter hint, did not know it existed... will give it a go and see if it is quicker.

Comment: Dictionaries win :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using Dictionaries instead of arrays.

I did a test with 1'000, 10'000 and 100'000 words and compared *all* elements (so not breaking when a duplicate was found) on a very regular computer. Using 1'000 elements was ready instantly, 10'000 took not much more that the blink of the eye, 100'000 2-3 seconds.

I don't know how your original data is from or how you will your arrays. The following code just copies the arrays into dictionaries and then loop over the keys of the first dictionary and looks if it is present in the second. No need to have the data sorted, and duplicates are eliminated automatically when the dictionary is build.

If your not familiar with Dictionaries: You need to add a reference to the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" (or change code to late binding).

```
Sub arrayTest()

    ' (omitting my test code to fill up the arrays)

    ' Create Dictionaries
    Dim d1 As New Dictionary
    Dim d2 As New Dictionary
    For x = 1 To UBound(aryA)
        If Not d1.Exists(aryA(x)) Then d1.Add aryA(x), vbNullString
    Next x
    
    For y = 1 To UBound(aryB)
        If Not d2.Exists(aryB(y)) Then d2.Add aryB(y), vbNullString
    Next
    
    ' Compare the dictionaries
    Counter = 0
    Dim k
    For Each k In d1.Keys
        If d2.Exists(k) Then Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
    Debug.Print "Done: " & Counter
    
End Sub
```

If you just need this check once and don't do anything with the data afterwards, of course it is not necessary to create the second dictionary:

```
For x = 1 To UBound(aryA)
    If Not d1.Exists(aryA(x)) Then d1.Add aryA(x), vbNullString
Next x

For y = 1 To  UBound(aryB)
    If d1.Exists(aryB(y)) Then Counter = Counter + 1
Next
Debug.Print "Done: " & Counter
```

Answer (score 0):

If both array are sorted you could just go through them considering their ordering in linear time:

Pseudo code:

```
i=0;
j=0;

while i < len(aryA) and j < len(aryB) do
    if aryA[i] == aryB[j] then 
        counter++;
        i++;
        j++;
    elseif aryA[i] > aryB[j] then 
        j++
    else 
        i++;
    fi
done
```